# S3 with versioning and Glacier transitioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

So I've got an S3 bucket with versioning enabled. On this bucket I also have a lifecycle rule that transitions the non-current versions of object to Glacier after 7 days. 
Now, I'd like to access an older version of this object. So as per S3's instructions, I initiated a restore of this object from Glacier that took several hours. 
Much to my surprise, it looks like the Glacier restore didn't restore all the previous versions of the object to Standard storage that can let me read previous versions of the object. 
What needs to be done to achieve restoring all versions of the object to standard storage? 
The screenshot is attached: [image: Versions still on Glacier]

Edit: another screenshot showing glacier storage version is not downloadable even after restore:
[image]

Comment: Objects restored from Glacier do not revert to `Standard` -- they remain in the `Glacier` storage class, but become downloadable... but restoring an object should only be possible at the individual version level -- not all versions of the object, unless there are steps you have omitted from your question.  How did you know when the restore completed?  Is it possible that exactly one of the versions of your object has been restored?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm not sure I follow. I went to the bucket's object listing page, right-clicked on the object I wanted to restore, and then requested a glacier restore. The dialog that popped up said the restore might take up to 10 hours, which was the time period after which I checked the object again. But it looks like only some versions of the object were restored. Now when I right click on the object the `Restore` option is grayed out. I've added another screenshot showing that the version I'd like to download is not downloadable. How can restoration of specific versions be achieved?